# How to re-evaluate cl-defstruct during same Emacs session

Tags: eval

I am putting together a modification of a library that contains an existing `cl-defstruct` definition, and I am having problems redefining it after its initial evaluation.

**Q**:  How can I replace the old definition with the new one?  [It would be nice if I could wrap it in something so that `eval-buffer`, `eval-region`, and/or `require` will be sufficient to force its re-definition.]

**BEFORE**:

```lisp
(cl-defstruct
  (undo-tree-node
   (:type vector)   ; create unnamed struct
   (:constructor nil)
   (:constructor undo-tree-make-node
                 (previous undo
      &optional redo
                  &aux
                  (timestamp (current-time))
                  (branch 0)))
   (:constructor undo-tree-make-node-backwards
                 (next-node undo
      &optional redo
                  &aux
                  (next (list next-node))
                  (timestamp (current-time))
                  (branch 0)))
   (:copier nil))
  previous next undo redo timestamp branch meta-data)
```

**AFTER**:  Adding the word `count` at the very end.

```lisp
(cl-defstruct
  (undo-tree-node
   (:type vector)   ; create unnamed struct
   (:constructor nil)
   (:constructor undo-tree-make-node
                 (previous undo
      &optional redo
                  &aux
                  (timestamp (current-time))
                  (branch 0)))
   (:constructor undo-tree-make-node-backwards
                 (next-node undo
      &optional redo
                  &aux
                  (next (list next-node))
                  (timestamp (current-time))
                  (branch 0)))
   (:copier nil))
  previous next undo redo timestamp branch meta-data count)
```

Comment: AFAIK there's no need to do anything special, it just works, same as for `defun`.  If it doesn't, please report it as a bug.

Comment: @Stefan -- Thank you.  Hmmmm....  Perhaps something else in the same library is being set (when the library loads) that is dependent upon the initial definition and that something also needs to be redefined.  I'll work on tracking it down.

Comment: `cl-defstruct` creates a bunch of inlined functions, redefining updates those definitions but not their call sites.